# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autokeras.image_supervised'

Tags: auto-keras

Installed **AutoKeras** and **pre-reqs** in 3.6 Python environment using Anaconda.

Trying to test AutoKeras in Jupyter, but keep getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autokeras.image_supervised'

Comment: Give us with more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your error (code, error log, etc).

Answer (score 2):

```
from autokeras.image.image_supervised import load_image_dataset
```

works for me (seems they changed files' structure of project)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using autokeras-0.3.5

`from autokeras import ImageClassifier`

Answer (score 0):

if this problem is arised then there might be a chance that u might have not installed autokeras library in the enironment.... I got the same error in Colab notebook try this code

> `!pip install autokeras`

This might solve your problem.....